# Password URL link getting truncated

Tags: email, hyperlink

I send out Password reset links that are of the following format

https://example.com/login?email=123@456.com&tmpPas=qwertyuiopasdfghjkl

Some small percent of users are reporting that when they click the link the email and password parameters are not carried over to the website.

So far they have reported this issue on IE11 and Safari on Ipad. What could be causing this and what are the possible solutions to reduce the occurence.

I have been able to reproduce this on an Ipad mini each time. Even if i paste the URL in the browser it does trigger the reset flow. While from any other device it does work.

in the console logs i see this

```
SCRIPT5009: 'URLSearchParams' is not defined
```

Here is the relevant code

```
    let url = new URL(window.location.href);
    let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
    let emailAddress = (searchParams.get('email'));
    let tempPass = (searchParams.get('tmpPass'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Found that the URLSearchParams is not supported on all browsers. Found this code in this answer that did it https://stackoverflow.com/a/20097994